# Concatenation for search in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, concatenation

So, as part of a search function in a Ruby on Rails app, I've made Users searchable by first name and last name. However, when I type in their full name, it doesn't render any results. So, if a User is named John Smith, I can type in "John" or "Smith" and it will bring him up, but if I type in "John Smith" it doesn't recognize it.

I know that's because in my search code I only enabled first_name and last_name but not the User's full name. What's the proper way to concatenate the first and last names to solve this problem?

Here's the current code:

```
users = User.find_by_sql(['select *
    from users
    where first_name ilike ?
    or last_name ilike ?
    order by last_name limit ?', q, q, 100])
```

Comment: What would you want to happen if they searched for "Smith John"?

Comment: Hadn't considered that...probably would want it to display John Smith though

Comment: I would probably define a new method, e.g.

    **def full_name                                                                                                                                                                                     
      ([first_name, last_name] - ['']).compact.join(' ')                         
    end**

Comment: @Suomi that doesn't seem to be working. Would that then be used as follows?     `where first_name ilike ?
          or last_name ilike ?
          or full_name ilike ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code,

```
users = User.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM users WHERE (coalesce(users.first_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(users.last_name, '') ilike '%#{p.downcase}%' )"])
```

Comment: Thanks Debadatt, a slight alteration to your answer worked! `users = User.find_by_sql(["select * 
                          from users 
                          where (coalesce(users.first_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(users.last_name, '')) ilike ?
                          order by last_name limit ?", q, 100])`

Answer (score 0):

What about mysql [`concat`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm) ?

```
users = User.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
                           CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE ? 
                           ORDER BY last_name LIMIT ?", p, 100]
                         )
```

where p could be anything `John`, `Smith`, `John Smith`

Comment: Salil, thanks for the answer, doesn't seem to be working though :(